# SAS Change the first record

Tags: sas, reset

Let's imagine the following table ...

| obs | State | Imp | i | i2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | me | 100 | 100 |  |
| 2 | me | 90 | 100 | 100 |
| 3 | me | 80 | 100 | 100 |
| 4 | me | 70 | 100 | 100 |
| 5 | me | 1000 | 1000 | 100 |
| 6 | me | 900 | 1000 | 1000 |
| 7 | me | 800 | 1000 | 1000 |
| 8 | me | 0 | 1000 | 1000 |
| 9 | me | 2000 | 2000 | 1000 |
| 10 | me | 1900 | 2000 | 2000 |
| 11 | gu | 20 | 2000 | 2000 |
| 12 | ca | 40 | 2000 | 2000 |
| 13 | ca | 50 | 2000 | 2000 |
| 14 | ca | 30 | 2000 | 2000 |
| 15 | ca | 10 | 2000 | 2000 |

as you can see column "i2" is lag (i). What I want to do is:
1.- column "i" finds the maximum value as it progresses, so i want to reset that column
"i" every first "state", in order to get that maximum value of each state.
2.- modify the column "i2" so that it is as follows:
that each first value of "State" (obs 1-me, 11-gu and 12-ca) column "i" has the value
of column "imp"

| obs | State | Imp | i | i2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | me | 100 | 100 | 100 |
| 2 | me | 90 | 100 | 100 |
| 3 | me | 80 | 100 | 100 |
| 4 | me | 70 | 100 | 100 |
| 5 | me | 1000 | 1000 | 100 |
| 6 | me | 900 | 1000 | 1000 |
| 7 | me | 800 | 1000 | 1000 |
| 8 | me | 0 | 1000 | 1000 |
| 9 | me | 2000 | 2000 | 1000 |
| 10 | me | 1900 | 2000 | 2000 |
| 11 | gu | 20 | 20 | 20 |
| 12 | ca | 40 | 40 | 40 |
| 13 | ca | 50 | 50 | 40 |
| 14 | ca | 30 | 50 | 50 |
| 15 | ca | 10 | 50 | 50 |

i have tried with this code, but it doesn't work

```
data metodo;
set sa80;
    retain i;
    if first.state then i=max(imp);
    else i = max(imp,i);
    i2 = lag(i);
run;

data final;
set metodo;
    retain i2_aux;
    if first.state then i2_aux = total;
    else i2_aux = i2;
run;
```

Hope you could help, and thank you in advance

Comment: RETAINing a variable that already exists in the input data is not going to do anything.  The next time the SET statement executes the retained value is overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

The main thing it not use an existing variable as the new RETAINed variable because then each time the SET statement executes the value retained is replaced with the value read from the input.

It also helps if the data is sorted by the key variable, although you can use the NOTSORTED keyword on the BY statement to process grouped, but not sorted, data.

```
data have;
  input state $ imp ;
cards;
ca 40
ca 50
ca 30
ca 10
gu 20
me 100
me 90
me 80
me 70
me 1000
me 900
me 800
me 0
me 2000
me 1900
;

data want;
  set have ;
  by state notsorted;
  retain i;
  i=max(i,imp);
  if first.state then i=imp;
  i2=lag(i);
  if first.state then i2=imp;
run;
```

Results:

```
Obs    state     imp       i     i2

  1     ca        40      40      40
  2     ca        50      50      40
  3     ca        30      50      50
  4     ca        10      50      50
  5     gu        20      20      20
  6     me       100     100     100
  7     me        90     100     100
  8     me        80     100     100
  9     me        70     100     100
 10     me      1000    1000     100
 11     me       900    1000    1000
 12     me       800    1000    1000
 13     me         0    1000    1000
 14     me      2000    2000    1000
 15     me      1900    2000    2000
```

*Fixed order of resetting I and LAG(I) call.*

Comment: Thank you very much @Tom , you helped me a lot.   I found a new problem when run my program: Because my data is sorted by state, every second value of "i2", has the last value "i" of the last state. to remedy this situation, I added an i3 = lag (i) and took the first values ​​of state from "i2" and the rest from "i3".  Thank you again =)

Comment: Use two IF FIRST.STATE statements so that I is "fixed" before it is used in the call to LAG().  Some people use IFN() function instead. It works because IFN() executes all of the inputs every time so the LAG() always runs.  `i=ifn(first.state,imp,max(imp,i));i2=ifn(first.state,imp,lag(i));`